# Hibernate unsaved instance exception using @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I am getting an exception

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

thrown in the following code:

```
public void addThing(String key, String someData) {
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    booking.setData(someData);
    booking.setParent(this);
    bookings.put(key, thing);
}
```

The Parent mapping is:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name="thing", nullable=false)
@MapKeyColumn(name="key")
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
protected Map<String, Thing> things = Maps.newHashMap();
```

The child ('Thing') mapping is:

```
@ManyToOne
private Parent parent;
```

According to the Hibernate manual:

> There is no cascade option on an `ElementCollection`, the target objects are always persisted, merged, removed with their parent.

But - before I changed to the new `@ElementCollection` mapping so solve a problem where I was getting apparently phantom elements returned for a query, this code worked correctly.

I know I can save the element separately and then make a reference, but I prefer to have it done automatically, and I thought that was the way it is supposed to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `Thing`?  An entity, or an embeddable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` is not supposed to be used with collections of entities; it's used with collections of `@Embeddable`. If `Thing` is an entity, you don't use `@ElementCollection`, you use `@OneToMany`.

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) for `@ElementCollection`:

> Defines a collection of instances of a basic type or embeddable class